# type transform by using constructor in c++ didn't work?

Tags: c++

My code can't run well, can anybody tell me what happened to my otest.cpp?

```
: ~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
//filename: otest.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Complex;   // declaration

class Victor
{
    private:
            int x, y;
    public:
            Victor(int xx = 0, int yy = 0) { x = xx;  y = yy; }
            friend ostream & operator <<(ostream & ostr, Victor & v); 
//              operator Complex() { return Complex(x,y); }
            int getX() { return x;}
            int getY() { return y;}
            Victor(Complex & c) { x = c.getReal(); y = c.getImg(); }
};

class Complex
{
    private:
            int real, img;
    public:
            Complex(int re= 0, int im = 0) { real = re; img = im; }
            friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & ostr,Complex & c);
  //              operator Victor() { return Victor(real,img); }
            int getReal() { return  real;}
            int getImg() { return img; }
            Complex(Victor & v) { real = v.getX(); img = v.getY(); }
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ostr, Complex& c)
{       ostr << c.real << " + " <<c.img << " i";
    return ostr;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ostr, Victor v)
{
    ostr << "( " << v.x << ", " << v.y << " )" ;
    return ostr;
}

int main()
{
    Victor v1(3,5);
    Victor v2;

    Complex c1(5,6);
    Complex c2;

    v2 = Victor(c1);
    cout << v2 << endl;
    cout << c1<<endl;

    c2 = Complex(v1);
    cout << c2 <<endl;
    cout << v1 <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Can't run well` does not adequately describe your problem

Comment: Beeing named Victor myself, I assume you mean to name your class "Vector".

Comment: Do you get compilation errors? Then edit your question to include them all (unedited and complete). Does it crash when running? Then run in a debugger and at least get a backtrace and edit your question to include that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work through the errors in order, and fix each problem in turn.

First error:

```
test.cpp: In constructor ‘Victor::Victor(Complex&)’:
test.cpp:17:40: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Complex’
             Victor(Complex & c) { x = c.getReal(); y = c.getImg(); }
```

You can't use the `Complex` type here since it hasn't been defined yet. Just declare the function at this point:

```
Victor(const Complex &);
```

and define it after the definition of `Complex`

```
Victor::Victor(const Complex & c) { x = c.getReal(); y = c.getImg(); }
```

(I took the liberty of adding `const` since that's appropriate here. You might also want to rename the class `Vector`, since it appears to represent a vector not a victor.)

Second error:

```
test.cpp:10:17: error: ‘int Victor::x’ is private
test.cpp:43:23: error: within this context
    ostr << "( " << v.x << ", " << v.y << " )" ;
```

This is because you declare a function with one signature (taking its second argument by reference)

```
friend ostream & operator <<(ostream & ostr, Victor & v);
```

and define a different overload taking its argument by value:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ostr, Victor v)
```

Make the both match; `const Victor&` is the most appropriate type. Alternatively, you could define the function within the class definition:

```
class Victor
{
    // ...
    friend ostream & operator <<(ostream & ostr, const Victor & v) {
        return ostr << "( " << v.x << ", " << v.y << " )" ;
    }
    // ...
};
```

Or you could implement the function using the public interface, with no need for a `friend` declaration:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ostr, const Victor & v) {
    return ostr << "( " << v.getX() << ", " << v.getY() << " )" ;
}
```

After fixing those errors, the code compiles and produces sensible-looking output.

Comment: I need some time to digest what you said, but thanks, I am appreciate all of you. what a poor english,Haha!

Answer (score 0):

The code shall not be compiled because in this point where constructor

```
Victor(Complex & c) { x = c.getReal(); y = c.getImg(); }
```

is defined the compiler knows nothing whether class `Complex` has methods `getReal` and `getImg`

You have only do declare the constructor in class `Victor` and define it only after the definition of class `Complex`.

Take into account that it would be better that some member functions and objects would have qualifier const. For example functions `getReal` and `getImg` could be declared with qualifier const. Also the parameter in the constructor above could be declared with  qualifier const.

```
Victor( cosnt Complex &c );
```

Or for example `operator <<` could be declared like

```
friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &ostr, const Complex &c );

friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &ostr, const Victor &v );
```